# Error coming in Post method for house price prediction

Tags: python, flask

Error is coming while i run my http url in Postman or Apidog application for Post method
error is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.
```

Response HTTP code error: Returned 404 while expected 200.
Response data differs from API specification
The format of the response data is not JSON

Code is

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import util

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_location_names', methods=['GET'])
def get_location_names():
    response = jsonify({
        'locations': util.get_location_names()
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response

@app.route('/predict_home_price', methods=['POST'])
def predict_home_price():
    total_sqft = float(request.form['total_sqft'])
    location = request.form['location']
    bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
    bath = int(request.form['bath'])

    response = jsonify({
        'estimated_price': util.get_estimated_price(location,total_sqft,bhk,bath)
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Python Flask Server For Home Price Prediction...")
    util.load_saved_artifacts()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please show your postman request, especially what url and port you are calling in testing POST request. If you start flask in development mode you do remember that by default it is starting on port 5000?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict_home_price . This is the url for postman request. After running the python file in cmd I got above url.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, run you app in debug mode to make it verbose and refreshing server when code changes:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

Next, pay attention to logs in your flask console when running, for example look at the example below:

[image: flask console example]

If your scripts has some errors or you hit wrong url - you should see it here.

When running Postman requests pay attention if your url is really correct (look at the space, white character (%20) I added at the end of second request in my example - it return as 404).

Your full Postman request should look something like:

[image: postman example]